# How to force a memory location to be valid in ACSL?

Tags: frama-c, acsl

I define device accesses as thus

```
volatile struct mydevice * const dev = (struct mydevice *)MY_DEVICE_ADDRESS;
```

I've modeled the accesses using

```
@ volatile dev->somereg reads somereg_read writes somereg_write;
```

Now the problem is that when I enable RTE checks, the generated validity checks can't be proved

```
/*@ assert rte: mem_access: \valid(dev->somereg); */
```

Is there any way to annotate my code such that MY_DEVICE_ADDRESS up to MY_DEVICE_ADDRESS+sizeof(struct mydevice) is considered valid?

EDIT: Here's an attempt that does not work

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define MY_DEVICE_ADDRESS (0x80000000)

struct mydevice {
  uint32_t somereg;
  uint32_t someotherreg;
};

volatile struct mydevice * const dev = (struct mydevice *)MY_DEVICE_ADDRESS;

/*@ axiomatic Physical_Memory {
     axiom Dev: \valid((struct mydevice*)MY_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
  } */

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  //@ assert \valid(dev);
  //@ assert \false;
  return 0;
}
```

Run with

> frama-c-wp -wp-rte -wp-init-const -wp-model Typed test.c

Comment: I somehow doubt that the problem you describe is related to the `volatile` nature of your memory location (even though this is indeed the source of other problems). From what you describe, I suspect that `MY_DEVICE_ADDRESS` is an absolute physical address (e.g. 0xdeadbeef). Could you provide a MWE and indicate which plug-in you intend to use (again, I suppose this is WP, which, I'm afraid, will not be able to prove anything about absolute memory address)

Comment: Yes it's WP and yes it's an absolute physical address. That's what I'm afraid of, I'll see if the developers have a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the only way to have the assertion proved is to put an axiomatic block of the form

```
/*@ axiomatic Physical_Memory {
     axiom Dev: \valid((struct mydevice*)MY_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
     // add more if you have other physical memory accesses
  } */
```

There is an option in the kernel `-absolute-valid-range <min-max>` to indicate that dereferencing a pointer within the given interval is OK, but only EVA is able to take advantage of it (I'm afraid this is too low-level for WP's memory models).

Note in addition that you can pass option `-wp-init-const` to WP to indicate that it should add in its context the fact the global `const` variables are always equal to their initial value.

**Edit**

As mentioned in the comments, the proposed axiom is indeed inconsistent with WP's memory model. The bulk of the issue lies in the fact that in said model a numeric address `0xnnnn` is apparently defined as `shift(global(0),0xnnnn)`. As can be seen in e.g. `$FRAMAC_SHARE/wp/ergo/Memory.mlw`, `global(0)` has a `base` of `0`, and so has the `shift` (which modifies only the `offset`). The definition of `valid_rw` imposes a strictly positive `base`, hence the contradiction.

This has to be fixed at WP's level. However, there are a few workarounds available while waiting for a new Frama-C release:

- if you don't need to write to the physical location, you can replace `\valid` by `\valid_read` in the axiomatic. Definition of `\valid_read` in the model does not have the `base>0` requirement, hence the axiom will not lead to a contradiction.
- if you can afford modifying the sources, make `dev` an `extern` declaration (or define `dev` as being equal to an `extern` declaration `abstract_dev`), and use the abstract constant in the axiom: in this way, you won't have the equality `dev.base==0` in the logic model, removing the contradiction.
- finally, you can patch the memory model in `$FRAMAC_SHARE/wp/ergo/Memory.mlw` (and `$FRAMAC_SHARE/wp/why3/Memory.why` and `$FRAMAC_SHARE/wp/coq/Memory.v` depending on your choice of provers). The easiest way to do that would probably to make `global` rely on an abstract base, as in:

```
logic global_base: int

function global(b: int) : addr = { base = global_base + b; offset = 0 }
```

(Note of course that this answer does in no way guarantee that this does not introduce other issues in the model).

Comment: I thought it was working but then I realized it made things inconsistent. If I do "//@ assert \valid((struct mydevice*)MY_DEVICE_ADDRESS);" followed by "//@ assert \false", the proof goes through.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. I think that at this point you really must provide a MWE to indicate _exactly_ what leads to this situation.

Comment: I just added it to my main post.

Comment: Making `dev` `extern` seems to work and still be consistent. However, I have to manually do it with every register such as `axiom somereg_valid: \valid(&dev->somereg);` then `axiom someotherreg_valid: \valid(&dev-> someotherreg);`. Any way to do it all at once?

Comment: Normally, `axiom dev_valid: \valid(dev)` should imply both `somereg_valid` and `someotherreg_valid`, at least as long as you can afford to represent your physical layout in a single `struct`. If you have different physical bases, you'll need one axiom for each of them. Feel free to open a new question if you have issues with this representation.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know (I've tried a lot too).

The only workaround I found is:

```
struct mydevice MY_DEVICE_STRUCT;
volatile struct mydevice * const dev = & MY_DEVICE_STRUCT;
```

You need to "instantiate" the memory because this is what the underlying LLVM expects. For sure it would be nice to force this through an ACSL notation.

Comment: The problem is that I need to map the device registers to a specific physical address. I guess I can try some linker tricks and see if that works.